# Cannot implicitly convert type "string" to "string[]"

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying add items to listbox with name and path, I'm getting this eror:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `string` to `string[]`

```
string path = textbox1.Text;
string[] FileName, FilePath;

DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();

foreach( FileInfo fileInfo in files)
{
    FileName = fileInfo.FullName; // Here 
    FilePath = fileInfo.Name; // and here 
    listbox2.Items.Add(fileInfo.FullName);
}
```

Comment: Why have you declared the `FileName` and `FilePath` variables as string arrays rather than just string variables? How do you expect to be able to assign a single string value to an array variable?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the files? As it stands, you don't use `FileName` or `FilePath` at all.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want an array of filenames and paths to be used later in your code? Because currently you're not using them at all in the sample you've provided. Additionally, your code already does exactly what you said you're trying to do: add items to a listbox. Then you don't do anything with `FileName` or `FilePath`. So, not only is this NOT a question, but it looks like everything you want to is done. What's the problem?

Comment: Re-reading your code, you have `FileName` which you're assigning `FullName` (contains the path) and then `FilePath` you assign `Name` (just the name, no path). That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 4):

You've declare this:

```
string[] FileName, FilePath;
```

So assigning this:

```
FileName = fileInfo.FullName; // Here 
FilePath = fileInfo.Name; // and here
```

Is assigning strings (fileInfo.FullName is a string for example) to arrays of strings.

What you're trying to do is make a list of these, so define lists and add the values:

```
string path = textbox1.Text; 
var FileNames = new List<string>(); 
var FilePaths = new List<string>();

DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path); 
FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();

foreach( FileInfo fileInfo in files) {
    FileNames.Add(fileInfo.FullName); // Here 
    FilePaths.Add(fileInfo.Name); // and here 
    listbox2.Items.Add(fileInfo.FullName); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `FileName` and `FilePath` as `string[]`.  It appears like you intended them to each contain single string values.

```
string[] FileName, FilePath;
```

change them to `string`

```
string FileName, FilePath;
```

Comment: It seems less likely that he wants a singular string, as he's assigning these variables a value while looping over a collection. So with a 'regular' string, these variables would only contain the values of the last `FileInfo` object in his collection. If anything he wants to store the names and paths of every file in an array. But why he's assigning `FileInfo.FullName`, which includes the path, to `FileName` and `FileInfo.Path`, which does not include the name, to `FilePath` is anyones guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] FileName, FilePath;
```

You declare `FileName` and `FilePath` as arrays, but `FullName` and `Name` both return `string`, hence the error.

[FileSystemInfo.FullName Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx)
[FileSystemInfo.Name Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx)

Change your declaration to:

```
    string FileName, FilePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `FileName` and `FilePath` are declared as `string[]`, but you're attempting to assign a `string` to them. However, since you say you're trying to add a list of files with name and path to a listbox, you don't need the `FileName` or `FilePath` variables at all. What would be easier is to set the `DataSource` of the `ListBox` and set which property of the object to show:

```
listbox2.DisplayMember = "Name"; //The Name property from FileInfo
listbox2.DataSource = files;
```

Then, when it comes time to get the selected item, cast it as FileInfo:

```
var selectedFileInfo = (FileInfo)listbox2.SelectedItem;
var selectedFileName = selectedFileInfo.Name;
//etc
```

Answer (score 0):

It may prove better to simply declare `FileNames` and `FilePaths` to type `List<string>` and do `Add` in a single foreach loop, but here is a linq alternative.

---

```
string[] FileNames, FilePaths;
```

using anonymous function delegates, in two linq operations.

```
FileNames = files.Select( f => f.FullName).ToArray();
FilePaths = files.Select( f => f.Name).ToArray();
listBox2.AddRange(files.Select(FileNames)); //AddRange can take either IEnumerable<T> or T[] as a parameter
```

---

If you build the expression before hand, it becomes a little bit more clear (and perhaps more optimized), for you're not declaring anonymous delegate functions.

```
// these can be declared out of function scope as readonly..
Func<FileInfo, string> SelectFullName = (f) => f.FullName;
Func<FileInfo, string> SelectName = (f) => f.Name;

FileNames = files.Select(SelectFullName).ToArray();
FilePaths = files.Select(SelectName).ToArray();
listBox2.AddRange(FileNames);
```

The advantage to the linq method is that you're not going to be Enumerating through `FileNames` and `FilePaths` when adding items